# Wordpress and ninja forms - styling forms

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, browser, styles

I need some help to style a form.

I tried some CSS but the form has no background color, could someone help me?

```
 #nf-form-8-cont {
     background-color: rgb(214, 214, 194,0.5); 
     padding: 15px;
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #444;
     border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: You have a incorrect rule on you background-color ... if you have a opacity value it  should be `rgba` instead `rgb`.   ex rgba(214, 214, 194, 0.5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using RGBA but have it set as RGB. Try:

```
background-color: rgba(214, 214, 194, 0.5);
```

Comment: Great to hear! If this is set please mark this question answered (checkmark underneath the voting arrows)